# Android worker - update and preserve state across retries

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

Kotlin/Android novice here :). I'm playing around with chunked uploads using a CoroutineWorker and don't see a built-in way to maintain state for my worker in case a retry happens, but I'm having sort of a hard time believing smth like that would be missing...

My use case is the following:

1. Create the worker request with the path to the file to upload as input data
2. Worker loops over the file and performs uploads in chunks. The latest uploaded `chunkIndex` is being tracked.
3. In case of an error and subsequent `Retry()`, the worker *somehow retrieves* the current chunk index and resumes rather than starting from at the beginning again.

So basically, I really just need to preserve that `chunkIndex` flag. I looked into setting progress, but this seems to be hit or miss on retries (worked once, wasn't available on another attempt).

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    try {
        // TODO check if we are resuming with a given chunk index
        chunkIndex = ...

        // do the work
        performUpload(...)

        return Result.success()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // TODO cache the chunk index


        return Result.retry()
    }
}
```

Did I overlook something, or would I really have to store that index outside the worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in GB's answer, there seems to be no way to cache data with in the worker, or do a `Result.retry(data)`. I ended up just doing a quick hack with `SharedPreferences` instead.

Solution below. Take it with a grain of salt, I have a total of ~10 hours of Kotlin under my belt ;)

```
var latestChunkIndex = -1

override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        // get cached entry (simplified - no checking for fishy status or anything)
        val transferId = id.toString()
        var uploadInfo: UploadInfo = TransferCache.tryGetUpload(applicationContext, transferId) ?: TransferCache.registerUpload(applicationContext, transferId, TransferStatus.InProgress)

        if(uploadInfo.status != TransferStatus.InProgress) {
            TransferCache.setUploadStatus(applicationContext, transferId, TransferStatus.InProgress)
        }

        // resolve the current chunk - this will allow us to resume in case we're retrying
        latestChunkIndex = uploadInfo.latestChunkIndex

        // do the actual work
        upload()

        // update status and complete
        TransferCache.setUploadStatus(applicationContext, id.toString(), TransferStatus.Success)
        Result.success()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (runAttemptCount > 20) {
            // give up
            TransferCache.setUploadStatus(applicationContext, id.toString(), TransferStatus.Error)
            Result.failure()
        }

        // update status and schedule retry
        TransferCache.setUploadStatus(applicationContext, id.toString(), TransferStatus.Paused)
        Result.retry()
    }
}
```

Within my `upload` function, I'm simply keeping track of my cache (I could also just do it in the exception handler of the `doWork` method, but I'll use the cache entry for status checks as well, and it's cheap):

```
private suspend fun upload() {
    while ((latestChunkIndex + 1) * defaultChunkSize < fileSize) {

        // doing the actual upload
        ...

        // increment chunk number and store as progress
        latestChunkIndex += 1
        TransferCache.cacheUploadProgress(applicationContext, id.toString(), latestChunkIndex)
    }
}
```

and the `TransferCache` looking like this (note that there is *no* housekeeping there, so without cleanup, this would just continue to grow!)

```
class UploadInfo() {
    var transferId: String = ""
    var status: TransferStatus = TransferStatus.Undefined
    var latestChunkIndex: Int = -1

    constructor(transferId: String) : this() {
        this.transferId = transferId
    }
}


object TransferCache {

    private const val PREFERENCES_NAME = "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.transfercache"
    private val gson = Gson()

    fun tryGetUpload(context: Context, transferId: String): UploadInfo? {
        return getPreferences(context).tryGetUpload(transferId);
    }


    fun cacheUploadProgress(context: Context, transferId: String, transferredChunkIndex: Int): UploadInfo {
        getPreferences(context).run {
            // get or create entry, update and save
            val uploadInfo = tryGetUpload(transferId)!!
            uploadInfo.latestChunkIndex = transferredChunkIndex
            return saveUpload(uploadInfo)
        }
    }


    fun setUploadStatus(context: Context, transferId: String, status: TransferStatus): UploadInfo {
        getPreferences(context).run {
            val upload = tryGetUpload(transferId) ?: registerUpload(context, transferId, status)
            if (upload.status != status) {
                upload.status = status
                saveUpload(upload)
            }

            return upload
        }
    }


    /**
     * Registers a new upload transfer. This would simply (and silently) override any
     * existing registration.
     */
    fun registerUpload(context: Context, transferId: String, status: TransferStatus): UploadInfo {
        getPreferences(context).run {
            val upload = UploadInfo(transferId).apply {
                this.status = status
            }
            return saveUpload(upload)
        }
    }


    private fun getPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFERENCES_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
    }


    private fun SharedPreferences.tryGetUpload(transferId: String): UploadInfo? {
        val data: String? = getString(transferId, null)
        return if (data == null)
            null
        else
            gson.fromJson(data, UploadInfo::class.java)
    }


    private fun SharedPreferences.saveUpload(uploadInfo: UploadInfo): UploadInfo {
        val editor = edit()
        editor.putString(uploadInfo.transferId, gson.toJson(uploadInfo))
        editor.apply()
        return uploadInfo;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a pretty good use-case but unfortunately **you cannot cache data within `Worker` class or pass on the data to the next `Worker` object on retry!** As you suspected, you will have to store the index outside of the `WorkManager` provided constructs!

Long answer,

The `Worker` object can receive and return data. It can access the data from `getInputData()` method. If you [chain tasks](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#unique), the output of one worker can be input for the next-in-line worker. This can be done by returning `Result.success(output)` (see below code)

```
public Result doWork() {
        int chunkIndex = upload();

        //...set the output, and we're done!
        Data output = new Data.Builder()
            .putInt(KEY_RESULT, result)
            .build();
        return Result.success(output);
}
```

So the problem is we cannot return data for the retry case, only for failure and success case! (`Result.retry(Data data)` method is missing!)

Reference: official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced) and [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.Result#summary).

Comment: I suspected so, but hope springs eternal ;)
I'll just go for SharedPreferences instead, I guess. Pity that I'll have to do the housekeeping that way. Thanks!